# display text from plain text in textView on button click

Tags: android, kotlin, showtext

I want that after pressing the button with the "create" id, the text from the textview that was manually entered in plaintext is displayed

I have plaintext and button.

In plaintext I write "test" or something like this and then I click button, this text should be displayed below in textview

Answer (score 0):

On button press (the click listener) take the text in the plaintext (input or edittext view i guess):

```
val plainText = yourEditTextView.text.toString()
```

and to set the text in our textView:

```
textView.text = plainText
```

This should do the job.